# Prompt login/password with .htaccess on Azure Container

Tags: azure, .htaccess, containers

I'm looking for implementing an .htaccess on Azure Container, but I don't think this is the proper way to implement a request access on Azure Container, because this is maybe different from Apache?

I want to add this .htaccess for specifics files on container root. Here is my .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "^(index|standalone|standalone-async|spa).html$">
    AuthName "Dialog prompt"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

Am I on the good way? And is this the best way to implement a dialog prompt on Azure Container?

Regards.

Comment: What are your web stacks?

Comment: What I want to put behind this .htaccess are just simple HTML pages.

Answer (score 0):

> this is maybe different from Apache?

- Yes, it is and if you are using the Windows App Service with the `php` stack, it uses the IIS not the Apache and the `.htaccess` is only for Apache. So that's why asked you the web stack.
- If you are using a Windows App Service, try to use the `web.config` from `.htaccess` by putting all the applicable rules.
- If you are using a php on a Linux App Service, make sure to re-check the major version like in the given below reference.
- It is important that where we are placing this `.htaccess` file.

***The target file that begins with `index or whateverpage` & it ends with .html***

```cs
<FilesMatch "^(index|whateverpage)\.html$">  
AuthName  "Dialog prompt"  
AuthType  Basic  
AuthUserFile /.htpasswd 
Require valid-user 
</FilesMatch>
```

***References:***
[Azure Web App Doesn’t Read HTAccess File](https://tutorialsforcloud.com/2022/01/01/azure-web-app-doesnt-read-htaccess-file/),

[Use of .htaccess file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file).